# Nigerian passport with UK ILR

Tags: visas, poland, nigerian-citizens

Can I travel to Poland with my Nigerian passport with UK ILR with my Belgian girlfriend? We both live in the UK.

Just wanting to know if I can travel to poland from the UK with my passport for a few days without visa due to Brexit.

Comment: Are you asking if you need a visa, or if Poland has some sort of "no Nigerians allowed" rule?

Comment: You will need a visa. If the Polish authorities recognize your relationship with your girlfriend as stable, you may go through the simplified procedure. If not, you need a normal visa.

Comment: +1 to @o.m. this should have been an anwer, not a comment though.

Comment: @rvs, it is a duplicate but I didn't have the time to find the best match. So no answer, just a comment.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.